# When does "build" happen for TypeScript/JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, build, vite

I'm new to code deployment and would like to know how 'production deployment is done' in real life. I know the high level concept; write your code, build it, and deploy it. But that't it. I googled this, but there was nothing helpful to get me to understand this.

Assume the tech stack is TypeScript (+Vite) and Node.js, then the deployment environment is AWS (preferably AWS SAM). There is "build" command in package.json (build: tsc && whatever) - I know it should be used at some point.

My question is when is this command used? And who executes this command?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your application, the build command is run by the service provider before it assigns the new code to a domain. The deployment can be triggered in a number of ways, including manually, via command line, or through GitHub merges into a specific branch.

If you are running your code locally, you have to run it yourself before you are able to run the program on your machine.

Comment: What is the service provider in this case? Where the app is running (e.g.AWS)?